# Trimming polygon based on its intersection with another polygon using shapely

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, overlapping-features, differences

I have two polygons intersecting with one another (x1 and x2). How can i trim x2 by the area it intersects with x1, such that x1 and x2 no longer overlap and x1 area/shape remains constant.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

x1 = Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)])
x2 = Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)])

if x1.overlaps(x2):
    print('yes')
```

Comment: Try the [`difference()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.difference), i.e. `x3 = x2.difference(x1)`.

Comment: yes, that does it. Thanks!